# How does eBay Suggest work?

Tags: javascript, autosuggest

We need the eBay Suggest function for an eBay Mashup!

Usually we thought it works like:
http://include.ebaystatic.com/autofill/f/77/1299871198/t/e/s/t.js -> t/e/s/t

but it doesn’t! - iphone works like:
http://include.ebaystatic.com/autofill/f/77/1299871198/i/p/h.js 
http://include.ebaystatic.com/autofill/f/77/1299871198/i/p/h/o.js 
http://include.ebaystatic.com/autofill/f/77/1299871198/i/p/h/o0.js 
http://include.ebaystatic.com/autofill/f/77/1299871198/i/p/h/o1.js

and trockner like:
http://include.ebaystatic.com/autofill/f/77/1299871198/t/r/o/c.js 
http://include.ebaystatic.com/autofill/f/77/1299871198/t/r/o/c0.js 
http://include.ebaystatic.com/autofill/f/77//1299871198/t/r/o/**c8**.js

c8?????

I don't see a system behind the suggest function?
You may test the function in the searchbox on http://www.ebay.com

Who could help? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that each page like /t/r/o/c.js is suggestions for words starting with "troc", then /t/r/o/c0.js is the second page, /t/r/o/c1.js is the third page  ... /t/r/o/c8.js is the tenth page of results.